# If $f$ measurable positive, is there a sequence of simple function that converge decreasly to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A famous theorem says that if $f\geq 0$ is measurable, then there is an increasing sequence of simple function $(\varphi _n)$ s.t. $\varphi _n\nearrow f$. Then we can define $$\int_{\mathbb R}f:=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}\varphi _n.$$

Now my question is : in these conditions, (i.e. $\geq 0$ and measurable), is there a decreasing sequence of simple function $(\psi_n)$ s.t. $\psi_n\searrow f$ ?

**Attempts**

I would say no because otherwise we could define $$\int f=\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb R}\psi_n,$$ and monotone convergence theorem (MCT) would work as well. But I know that MCT doesn't hold, so I guess this result is not correct. Does someone has a counter example ? And if not, does this result hold ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. But your  explanation why makes no sense at all: The fact that there would be problems using $(\psi_n)$ to define $\int f$ does not show that $(\psi_n)$ does not exist. You say "no because otherwise[...],
and monotone convergence theorem (MCT) would work as well. But I know that MCT doesn't hold,"  This is unclear. MCT *does* hold - I can prove it.

**Hint:** A simple function is *bounded*.

Comment: What do you mean by MCT does hold ? That if $\psi_n\searrow f$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty }\int \psi_n=\int f$ ?

Comment: No of course I don't mean that. MCT is a theorem, and that thing you suggest is false.